# How to shape border spikes in CSS

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

I need to make the spikes with border like in the picture. Unfortunately I don't have the design, so no png or svg available. How can I make this in CSS? Is it even possible? I've been trying to make it all day, but the best I could come up with was a tutorial on how to make rounded zig zags in css and that's not even close to what I need.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? I just need something to get me in the right direction. Thanks.[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24599961/7427111.
Once you are able to get the shape, you should use `shadow` to get the border.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh what do you mean by shadow? How is it gonna help me get the border? Thanks for the reference

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186688/drop-shadow-for-png-image-in-css
Check this out. I will try to recreate it in few hours when I get the time.

Comment: I will check it. Thanks I would really appreciate to see yours take on this one.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to re-create this using the Canvas Tag. It's not using CSS purely, instead using a bit of js. Hope that helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
      Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

    <script>
      var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      ctx.moveTo(0, 100);
      ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
      ctx.lineTo(250, 50);
      ctx.lineTo(350, 150);
      ctx.lineTo(400, 100);
      ctx.lineTo(500, 100);
      ctx.stroke();

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: After a bit of research, found out you can insert js. in wordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `drop-shadow` ([Dudley's Link for Drop-Shadow](http://thenewcode.com/600/Creating-a-True-CrossBrowser-Drop-Shadow-Effect-With-CSS3-&-SVG))

> `filter: drop-shadow(0px -10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 255, 1));`

```css
.outer {
  background-color: #DF290D;
  width: 300px;
}

.outer img {
  width: 100%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px -10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 255, 1));
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/79/Mountain_icon_%28Noun_Project%29.svg/2000px-Mountain_icon_%28Noun_Project%29.svg.png" />
</div>
```

Instead of creating a spike using CSS, better to create an image in [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) or something and give it drop-shadow, it will save much of your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired effect using plain CSS and HTML with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements.

I've made a start on the design so far and will look to complete but you can see how to make a start. A lot of this will be trial and error but hopefully it can work to your desired output.

```css
body {
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#title {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

#title .left {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 70px
  font-size: 30px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
}
#title .left:after {
    content: '';
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-width: 2px 2px 0 0;
    transform: skew(-14deg) rotate(-44deg);
    width: 14px;
    height: 38px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -44px;
    right: -15px;
    background: lightgrey;
}

#title .right {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="title">
  <div class="left">Sole</div>
  <div class="right">Source</div>
</div>
```